# How to draw matter.js objects using "WebGLRenderer" from three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer, matter.js

I know that matter.js is a 2D implementation, and three.js focuses on 3D. However, I need these technologies to go together in the specific case. I also found out that it is possible to include a target renderer for matter.js (https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Rendering). I wonder how to involve "WebGLRenderer()" from three.js. I prefer any answers with the pieces of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom renderer for this. See this [Matter.js three.js example](http://goo.gl/KJ6G8M) for a possible option. Also see [Using a custom renderer](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Rendering#using-a-custom-renderer) in the wiki.

Comment: I love it. How would one go about using MouseConstraint here? I took out the Three OrbitControls and I tried:`var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
     mouse: Mouse.create(renderer.domElement)
 });
 World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);`